# Readfile issue PHP

Tags: php, download, readfile

I'm using the following :

```
@header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
@header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
@header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
@header("Content-Length: ".$row['file_size']);
@header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$row['artist'] . " - " .$row['title']."\"");
@header("Content-type: audio/mpeg;\r\n");
```

to start a download, now for some reason its giving me

**Warning**:  readfile(http://theurl.com/downloads/the file some spaces.mp3) [function.readfile]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
 in **/home/belgin/public_html/dl.php** on line **29**

now the url is valid, I've triple checked but could it be because there's spaces in the file name? And if so how can i fix that? Thanks

reafile line :

```
readfile(http://domain.com/downloads/Warp 1.9_The Bloody Beetroots_320000.mp3)
```

Comment: Show the `readfile` line and we can show you how to escape it.

Comment: Apart from possibly urlencode()'ing the URL, your code snippet does not enclose the URL (a string) in quotes?!

Comment: I don't know if your `readfile()` line looks exactly as you put it here because here it is missing quotes around the URL, and Ascherer is correct that URLs have to be encoded, spaces are not allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your going to need to urlencode() and html_entities() the url or filename or whatever

Comment: i hope its something like readfile($filename), if it is, change it to this
readfile(html_entities(urlencode($filename)));

Comment: It should be `readfile(urlencode($filename));`, no `htmlentities()`, which is only needed to escape strings that are to be used in (X)HTML (in tags, attributes or for display).

Comment: now i'm getting readfile(http://domain.com/downloads%2FWarp+1.9_The+Bloody+Beetroots_320000.mp3)  which isn't working (invalid url and everyhting)

Comment: ok, so you'll have to separaate the filename and the url

readfile("domain.com/downloads/".html_entities(urlencode($filename)))

Comment: Hm... my mistake I guess. `urlencode()` also encodes the `http://` part of the URL which includes `:` and `/`. You should only be encoding the file name part. But again, no `htmlentities()`.

Comment: the htmlentities wont hurt anything, infact it makes the urls look better. + instead of %20

Comment: `urlencode()` does that `+` (as opposed to `rawurlencode()` which generates `%20`). `htmlentities()` transforms characters for which there are SGML/HTML entities such as `&` to `&amp;` etc. The only reason it does not hurt (apart from giving your server more work) is because URL-encoded strings do not have any characters left that could be escaped by `htmlentities()`.

Comment: well, im mistaken then lol. Ive seen people doing the same thing i did, and thats what ive used, and its always worked for me, but if you dont need it, dont use it

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the url contains spaces. Do you escape it properly for use inside readfile()?

Answer (score 2):

**DO NOT** encode url! It will encode like `http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fsome%20song.mp3`. You just need to replace spaces. so use `str_replace` instead...

`readfile(str_replace(" ", "%20", $url));`

Answer (score 0):

urlencode() is not the way to go. As mentioned above, simply use str_replace().

Just another possibility here as to why its not working. This was the cause for me. Interestingly, file_exists was returning true but no form of serving the file to the public for download was working without having the below set correctly.

PHP has a setting called **open_basedir**

Make sure this is set correctly relevant to your hosting environment. open_basedir can be edited via php.ini